# SwiftUI - how to change text alignment of label in Toggle?

Tags: swift, swiftui, toggle, text-alignment

Code for Toggle in SwiftUI is this:

```
Toggle(isOn: $vibrateOnRing) {
    Text("Vibrate on Ring")
}
```

This will produce a toggle button with text label looking like this:

**Vibrate on Ring | [--empty space--] | Toggle**

I need a right-aligned text label, like this:

**[--empty space--] | Vibrate on Ring | Toggle**

How to do it in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here it is

[image: demo]

```
Toggle(isOn: $vibrateOnRing) {
    Text("Vibrate on Ring")
      .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. First I added this to Toggle and it didn't work. Adding to Text works as expected.

Comment: How to bring both in center?

Answer (score 12):

I was able to achieve this by decoupling the toggle button and the text label, that is:

```
HStack() {
    Spacer()
    Text("Vibrate on Ring")
    Toggle("", isOn: $vibrateOnRing).labelsHidden()
}
```

And for folks who are looking for a solution for center alignment, aka:

**[--empty space--] | Vibrate on Ring | Toggle | [--empty space--]**

simply add a trailing spacer:

```
HStack() {
    Spacer()
    Text("Vibrate on Ring")
    Toggle("", isOn: $vibrateOnRing).labelsHidden()
    Spacer()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, did not know about labelsHidden() !

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
Toggle(isOn: $selPer, label: {
    HStack {
        Spacer()
        Image(systemName: "thermometer.sun")
            .foregroundColor(ITheme.IColor.sfImg)
            .font(.system(size: 12))
        if selPer {
            Text("关")
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .font(ITheme.IFont.titleMin)
        } else {
            Text("开")
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .font(ITheme.IFont.titleMin)
        }
    }
})
```